# white-space at bottom of page

Tags: bug, design, meta, footer

white-space bug at bottom of page! happening on every page on meta.SE that I've tried!

[image]

Comment: I've noticed this for a while, never got around to reporting it.

Comment: Nope, it was always there, since the split and never got any real attention. As Oded says in the dupe's comments, it has low priority which essentially kills any chance of fixing it since there will always be higher priority bugs. /cc @Undo